# Start Mapbox Navigation UI using MapboxNavigation object

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I successfully start Mapbox navigation UI using this line of code:

`NavigationLauncher.startNavigation(MainActivity.this, options);`

But I want to start a navigation session using a `MapboxNavigation` object so that I can implement listeners EG: the `OffRouteListener`.

To do so I use the following code, but no navigation UI shows up.

I'm not even sure that `MapboxNavigation#startNavigation` is supposed to start any visual component.

```
MapboxNavigation mapboxNavigation = new MapboxNavigation(MainActivity.this, accessToken, mapboxNavigationOptions);
mapboxNavigation.addOffRouteListener(location -> {
   // do things
});
mapboxNavigation.startNavigation(directionsRoute);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/examples/mock-navigation/) in the Mapbox Android documentation shows how to start a visual navigation component using `MapboxNavigation#startNavigation`, in conjunction with an `OffRouteListener`. The relevant section of the source code (also linked [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/a544e77a713cd71b28990b523ec92d01075bf483/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/MockNavigationActivity.java#L149-L170)) is:

```
@OnClick(R.id.startRouteButton)
public void onStartRouteClick() {
  boolean isValidNavigation = navigation != null;
  boolean isValidRoute = route != null && route.distance() > TWENTY_FIVE_METERS;
  if (isValidNavigation && isValidRoute) {

    // Hide the start button
    startRouteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Attach all of our navigation listeners.
    navigation.addNavigationEventListener(this);
    navigation.addProgressChangeListener(this);
    navigation.addMilestoneEventListener(this);
    navigation.addOffRouteListener(this);

    ((ReplayRouteLocationEngine) locationEngine).assign(route);
    navigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
    mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
    navigation.startNavigation(route);
      mapboxMap.removeOnMapClickListener(this);
  }
}
```

The `navigation` variable is initialized [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/blob/a544e77a713cd71b28990b523ec92d01075bf483/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/services/android/navigation/testapp/activity/MockNavigationActivity.java#L91) as an instance of `MapboxNavigation`.

So, adding the lines

```
((ReplayRouteLocationEngine) locationEngine).assign(route);
mapboxNavigation.setLocationEngine(locationEngine);
mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
```

Before calling `mapboxNavigation.startNavigation(directionsRoute);` in your implementation should do the trick. You should also ensure that the `directionsRoute` object is a correctly formulated instance of the `DirectionsRoute` class.